# Reset a specific Input field on ant design form

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

How do I reset a specific input field, in this instance, title input field?
I know how to reset all fields (using `form.resetFields()`) but not a specific field on ant design

````
 <Form.Item name='Title' label='Title'>
                  <Input value={title} onChange={handleChange('title')} />
                </Form.Item>
<Form.Item name='Category' label='Category'>
                  <Select
                    placeholder='Select a category'
                    style={{ width: 420 }}
                    onChange={handleCategoryChange}
                  >
                    {categories.length > 0 &&
                      categories.map((c) => (
                        <Option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                          {c.name}
                        </Option>
                      ))}
                  </Select>
                </Form.Item>


  const handleCategoryChange = (e) => {
    ///reset Title field
  };```
````

Answer (score 7):

You are not showing the whole form, but since you are using `form.resetFields()` I am assuming that you are specifying some `initialValues` in your form tag. Let us say you have something similar to

```
const initValues = {
    Title: "Foo",
    Category: 123,
    ...
}

<Form
    initialValues={initvalues}
    ...
/>
```

What `form.resetFields()` does is set all field values back to their `initialValues`. What you want, then, is to reset only the `title` field to its initial value.

This can then be accomplished by

```
const handleCategoryChange = (e) => {
    form.setFieldsValue( { Title: initValues.Title } )
}
```

Comment: where did you assign form ?

Comment: just found `const [form] = Form.useForm();`